# How to echo client certificate of request?

Tags: rust, hyper

I am writing a simple TLS/HTTP server using hyper and rustls. I want to be able to echo the details of a request to the server by displaying information like tls version, extensions, headers, and body.

However, I'm not sure how I would be able to access and return any client cert if provided by the request (want to access cert.pem from `curl --i --cert ./cert.pem https://example.com/`) since it seems like hyper requests do not provide it.

Comment: Does curl actually send the certificate? I wouldn't expect it to do so, since it's a private certificate/key.

Comment: @PeterHall Actually, I'm not sure - will definitely look into it. Regardless, this question goes for requests sent by any medium that sends a client cert.

Comment: What I meant was, I wouldn't expect any client to send a private key or certificate. It would use it to sign messages but that's it. Hyper almost certainly doesn't see this - the TLS implementation would do that and the HTTP protocol knows nothing about it.

Comment: @PeterHall I think OP means the public TLS certificate from the server (since that is the only certificate involved in normal TLS requests), is that true? In that case, `curl --cert` might not be what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this, sadly. Maybe you could access the X.509 certificate from the underlying TLS connector (ex. [`get_peer_certificates` for rustls](https://docs.rs/rustls/0.18.1/rustls/trait.Session.html#tymethod.get_peer_certificates), [`peer_certificate` for OpenSSL](https://docs.rs/openssl/0.10.30/openssl/ssl/struct.SslRef.html#method.peer_certificate) or [native_tls](https://docs.rs/native-tls/0.2.4/native_tls/struct.TlsStream.html#method.peer_certificate))

Comment: @PeterHall client certificates certainly get sent to server during the handshake if the server wants them. The certificate part is not any more "private" than a server certificate is. The common file format contains both private key and certificate though.